# Delaying multiple calls to java webservice

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate, message-queue, telnet

I get around 20 calls to my webservice every hour but they all arrive at the same time. For each request I get I need to call a telnet server and execute some commands.

The problem is that the telnet server can not handle all these request.

Ways I have seen to handle this is either:
Add all requests to database and have a cron pick them up every 5 seconds.
Use some kind of a message queue.

What other ways are there and what would likely be the best approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest looking into implementing RabbitMQ. http://www.rabbitmq.com/

It's fairly simple to install/configure, then rather than shoving the requests into a database, you can just send them directly to a queue where the messages persist, even if MQ was to die/restart for some reason.

Then you can fashion up a simple consumers to pull messages from the queue at whatever rate you'd like.